# AFNetworkReachabilityManager return NO all the time

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
AFNetworkReachabilityManager*manger =[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager];
BOOL is=[manger isReachable];
```

**Why does it return NO all the time? I do know I connect the internet with wifi.**

Comment: can you provide more information?

Comment: did you start monitoring in appdelegates.m file ?

Comment: add this 2 thing in appdelegates.h file 

#import "Reachability.h"
 [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];

Comment: try again, [diagnose yourself](https://www.google.co.in/#q=check+internet+connection+afnetworking+objective+c).

Comment: `AFNetworking` version?

Comment: retry after connect with different network connection

Answer (score 0):

Requires some time to Determine network status.

So,**isReachable** right after startMonitoring will always return **false**.

You need check **isReachable** inside **setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock** ;

```
    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status){
          NSLog(@"network staus changed");
         //check for network related flag
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

`[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring]` will take little bit time to return proper value.

I'm using this code and this works for me!

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"Rechability : %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));

        switch (status) {
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            {
                // NO Internet Connection.
                break;
            }
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            {

                break;
            }
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            {

                break;
            }
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown:
            {

                break;
            }
            default: break;
        }
    }];
    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps, this is working code in my project.

**Step 1:**

```
//AppDelegate.m

[self startMonitoringTheNetwork];// Call this method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

**Step 2:**

```
#pragma mark - Interenet Connection Status

-(void)startMonitoringTheNetwork {

    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {

        switch (status) {

            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown:
                break;
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
                break;
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
                //available
                break;
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
                //not available
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }];
    //start monitoring
    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
}
```

**Step 3:**

> Add following class level method to CommonClass.h
>       + (BOOL) isInternetConnected;

**Step 4:**

> And implement above method to CommonClass.m

```
+(BOOL) isInternetConnected {

    BOOL isConnected = NO;

    if (!isConnected) {
        isConnected = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable;
    }

    return isConnected;
}
```

**Step 5:**

> Now you are ready to access to the internet status everywhere by importing that CommonClass.h i.e #import "CommonClass.h"

```
Bool isInternetConnected = [CommonClass isInternetConnected];
```

**Note :** Step 3 & 4 are not compulsory, you can directly access if you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Version of `AFNetworking`,

`Reachability` should be monitered when the app is launched,ie

you should write the below code in the `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method, so that the Rechability manager starts monitering the status when the application starts.

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        NSLog(@"Rechability : %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));

        switch (status) {
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            {
                // NO Internet Connection.
                break;
            }
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            {

                break;
            }
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            {

                break;
            }
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown:
            {

                break;
            }
            default: break;
        }
    }];
    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
```

If you want to know the status before performing some operation you can use:

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] isReachable];
```

If you want to know immediately if network is cut off, then you can post a `NSNotification` so that you can receive it anywhere and perform some operation